# Sink kafka topics in strict order

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I have generated new topics with Kafka Streams. I want to sink them to Postgres DB in correct way. In Postgres DB I have tables with foreign keys. Is it possible to set priority for topics because I don't know how to solve the problem with foreign keys (which I must have in Postgres if I add some new data) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way we can guarantee ordering events in Kafka is by the concept of keys into a single partition. So if your case is like you have data in two separate topics at the same time and need to start consuming the other only after events in one is consumed, am afraid this kind of orchestration is not built into Kafka. And it is hard to achieve it without some additional logic/tool outside of Kafka.

Comment: Well I think I have to implement my own solution to kafka sink connector. That will be a hard task.

Comment: I would suggest instead of building a solution of your own using Kafka or any orchestration, change the overall design/architecture. If you can control the upstream/publish to topics from sources, try that solution. Re-design solution.